# svg fill bg, leave patch transparent, or any other suggestion

Tags: svg

[image]

SVG code:

```
             <svg style="bottom: 0; position: absolute;"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                viewBox="0 0 800 30">

                <path
                    fill="#fafafa" 
                    fill-opacity="1" 
                    d="M 0 0 C 220 30 580 30 800 0"> 
                </path>
            </svg>
```

How can I invert svg path or fill the rest with white bg but leave svg patch transparent to parent background ?

Any help ?

Comment: What do you meen by _parent background_? Do you need to clip an HTML element so that it has a rounded border like the one in the svg code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the path so that the enclosed space is the negative of the current curve:

```
             <svg style="bottom: 0; position: absolute;"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            viewBox="0 0 800 30">

            <path
                fill="#fafafa" 
                fill-opacity="1" 
                d="M 0 0 C 220 30 580 30 800 0 v 30 h -800 z"> 
            </path>
        </svg>
```

The v 30 draws a 30 pixel line to the bottom of the page, the h -800 draws a line back to the left edge of the page, and the z draws a line back to the start of the shape.